# using a subclass of UITableViewCell in IB - Why is there a need to override drawRect:?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW12

In relation to subclassing `UITableViewCell`, the above link talks about the need to override `drawRect:` to explicitly draw the cells content.

But why is this necessary? Can we not just create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` in IB, add the required subviews in IB, create the required outlet connections and then set the values of these subviews programmatically.

Why is there a need to override `drawRect:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not required to override drawRect: any more than you are required to use the textField implementation methods for UIAlertView. Drawing the cell's content, however, can boost performance in some cases, particularly if you have multiple non-opaque layers and can draw them into one opaque cell, because the renderer doesn't have to composite and blend multiple times. By drawing into a single opaque layer, the hardware only has to blend right before it gets displayed on screen.

Note that if you don't experience lag or if you have animation in each cell themselves, then drawing will not help you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find in your link where it says you are supposed to subclass DrawRect method.
I don't think apple recommand it.

I have developped an entire app with a lot of tableControllers with custom tableViewCells, using nib files and never subclassing drawRect method.

I never noticed any problem, and my app passed successfully the app store review.

Comment: the link should take you straight to the section "Subclassing UITableViewCell". there they talk about overriding drawRect: I have no idea why. Simply doing it in IB seems to work for me. thanks for the response.

Comment: it says : "*Your subclass of UITableViewCell **could** draw all of its content in its drawRect: method ...*". It's not mandatory, but if you want to subclass it, "*you should be aware of the potential drawbacks of this approach*"